# How to use jquery pagination plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, pagination

I've created a webpage to display the array elements,
How to use the pagination plugin to display these contents 2 items per page,
I've tried jquery.pajinate.js and some other plugins, but I've not figured out how to use it,
Help me with any of the pagination plugins to solve this ..
Any guidance and help is appreciated..!

Here is the webpage that displays an array elements : http://jsfiddle.net/ztruc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please refer this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pintu31/wtc5A/3/)

i have just added `$('.message').hide().slice(0, 2).show(); //slice(startElement, endElement);` for pagination. In this way you can implement pagination to your site.

Comment: i have also created plugin for pagination https://github.com/pintu31/jquery-paginate

Comment: Thanks, I've tried your plugin and it displays a single element in first page when i set the array testContent with 5 elements and set the limit to 2